# Does MLflow support auto-logging of system resources like GPU, CPU, and memory usage?

Tags: mlflow

I'm currently working on a machine learning project and I'm using MLflow to track my experiments. However, I'm wondering if MLflow supports auto-logging of system resources like GPU, CPU, and memory usage like other tracking platforms such as W&B.

For those who are unfamiliar, here's an example of how it looks like in W&B:

[image]

I'd like to have this feature in MLflow as it would be very useful for optimizing my models and understanding the resource consumption of my experiments. If anyone has any information or insights on this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As of this [March 2023 GitHub issue](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/7983), there's no built-in capability for tracking usage of system resources like GPU, CPU, and memory. You'd have to add that logic into your training script and persist the data as metrics with `log_metric` or as a log file with `log_artifact`.

Comment: I believe the person who opened the post, and the issue, are the same.

Comment: I think they probably are the same person too, but that is the most recent GitHub issue where maintainers have confirmed the state of the feature.

Answer (score 0):

I found documentation on official sites about methods for tracking CPU, GPU, and RAM as of 2024.

link : https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/system-metrics/index.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).